# Change CSS class name dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to change the CSS class name of all the elements in a page with a particular class name (.k-textbox). I tried the below code but it does not hit inside the .each() function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $(".k-textbox").each(function () {
            //alert("a");
            $(this).removeClass("k-textbox");
            $(this).addClass("input-medium");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In the page i have a 3rd party grid control. the CSS class i have mentioned is inside that third party grid control.

below is the DOM object:

[image]

Comment: whether the input elements are created dynamically

Comment: Show us your html? maybe you have the class wrong or something

Comment: Although you don't need the `each`, this should work. Please add your HTML and any other JS code to the question so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Are those elements in the DOM created after the page has been loaded?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it's created dynamically

Comment: If the `.each` callback is not executed, it means that there are no elements with such a class at the moment you make the call.

Answer (score 6):

You should try to use chaining API provided by jQuery library:

```
$(".k-textbox").removeClass("k-textbox").addClass("input-medium");
```

**edit:**

As long as the elements are created dynamically you could try to run this code after those elements are created. But if you don't know when they are inserted into the code and doesn't have control over them you could try write simple `watch` function, i.e:

```
var watchTimer = setInterval(function () {
      var inputs = $('.k-textbox');
      if (inputs.length) {
          // clear interval
          clearInterval(watchTimer);

          // change class
          inputs.removeClass("k-textbox").addClass("input-medium");
      }
    }, 100);
```

Comment: While this is better syntax, logically it's no different to what the OP has. I'm not sure why it's being upvoted?

Comment: @chamara - does that inputs created dynamically after DOM is ready? And can you know when it's happen?

Comment: Do you have control over that when they are inserted? (click some button, call some function, etc...)

Answer (score -1):

use **[addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)** and **[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)**

```
$(".k-textbox").removeClass("k-textbox").addClass("input-medium");
```